# One sided bound for Lipschitz functions for gaussian variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, statistics, lipschitz-functions

Let $(X_1, . . . , X_n)$ be a vector of i.i.d. standard Gaussian variables,
and let $f : R^n → R$ be L-Lipschitz with respect to the Euclidean norm. Then the
variable $f(X) − E[f(X)]$ is sub-Gaussian with parameter at most L, and hence

$$ P\left[|f(X)-E[f(X)]| \geq t \right] \leq 2e^{\frac{t^2}{2L^2}}$$

Is there an equivalent bound for the one sided equivalent?
$$ P\left[f(X)-E[f(X)] \geq t \right]$$

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking for but here's a simple lower bound:

\begin{align}
2e^{\frac{t^2}{2L^2}} &\ge P(|f(X)-E[f(X)]|\ge t) \\
\iff &\\
1-2e^{\frac{t^2}{2L^2}}
&\le P(|f(X)-E[f(X)]|\le t)\\
&=P(\{X\in\Omega:f(X)-E[f(X)]\le t\}\cap\{X\in\Omega:f(X)-E[f(X)]\ge -t\})\\
&\le \min \{ P(f(X)-E[f(X)]\ge t) , P(f(X)-E[f(X)] \le -t)\}\\
&\le P(f(X)-E[f(X)]\ge t)
\end{align}